# XAML ItemsControl to repeat X number of times?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am working in a Windows Phone 8.1 application (non SL) and have a property on my ViewModel called `Apples` which has a value of `3`.

I want a repeater to draw `x` Apples (I have the image) where `x` is the value of `Apples` on my ViewModel.

How can I achieve this in XAML? I have the following at the moment:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Lives, Converter={}}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- image here -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I am guessing I need to somehow convert the integer into some sort of items?

Comment: Recommended naming convention is to use property name `AppleCount` for number and `Apples` for collection types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ItemsSource="{Binding SomeNumber, Converter={StaticResource NumberToItemsConverter}}"
```

```
public class NumberToItemsConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var number = (int)value;
        return Enumerable.Range(1, number);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

**Option one**

You need to create a list of apples, and bind the ItemsControl to it.
Here's an example:

```
int x = 3;
Apples = new ObservableCollection<Apple>(); 
/*your ViewModel must implement INotifyPropertyChanged so the UI will be
notified by the changes in the Apples list*/

for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
   Apples.Add(new Apple());
}
//now your ItemsControl has 3 apples
```

**Option two**
You create a custom control that does what I wrote above, in the code behind. In that control you create a dependency property of type int, and when that property is changed you can add items to your ItemsControl.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try it out with a GridView with 5 items (each of them styled as an apple). The GridView has its source backed by with `ObservableCollection`. When a life is "consumed", just remove an item from the collection.